# How to change an item id in a dictionary based on specific logic

Tags: javascript

I wish to change the name of an ID if it has 2 colors.

My simplified list looks like this:

```
var myList = [{'ID': 'ES', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'red'},
 {'ID': 'ES', 'volume': 2, 'color': 'red'},
 {'ID': 'ES', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'green'},
 {'ID': 'HH', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'red'},
 {'ID': 'HR', 'volume': 4, 'color': 'green'},
 {'ID': 'HR', 'volume': 4, 'color': 'red'},
{'ID': 'ES', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'red'}]
```

Logic: in the event there are 2 IDs that share different color - change the id of the red to __OLD.

example: in the list above the ID 'ES' has both green and red - so for the red change the ES to ES__OLD.

expected result:

```
var myList = [{'ID': 'ES__OLD', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'red'},
 {'ID': 'ES__OLD', 'volume': 2, 'color': 'red'},
 {'ID': 'ES', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'green'},
 {'ID': 'HH', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'red'},
 {'ID': 'HR', 'volume': 4, 'color': 'green'},
 {'ID': 'HR__OLD', 'volume': 4, 'color': 'red'},
{'ID': 'ES__OLD', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'red'}]
```

What have I tried:

```
var keys = new Set();
myList.forEach(i=>{
  
  keys.add(i['ID']+' '+i['color'])
})
```

result:

```
0: "ES red"
1: "ES green"
2: "HH red"
3: "HR green"
4: "HR red"
```

expected

Problem: now I have to eliminate those who has only one color (in the example HH) and then iterate  on myList and make the change.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Your logic is unclear. Please provide your expected final output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is the solution that you are looking for.

**Logic**

- Loop through the nodes in the array `myList`
- Check whether the array `myList` has an another node with same `ID`
- If the node with same `ID` exist and the color of that node is `red` update the `ID` of the node.
- Push the new node to the `accumulator` array.

**Working Example**

```js
var myList = [
  { 'ID': 'ES', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'red' },
  { 'ID': 'ES', 'volume': 2, 'color': 'red' },
  { 'ID': 'ES', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'green' },
  { 'ID': 'HH', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'red' },
  { 'ID': 'HR', 'volume': 4, 'color': 'green' },
  { 'ID': 'HR', 'volume': 4, 'color': 'red' },
  { 'ID': 'ES', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'red' }
];
const result = myList.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  console.log(curr, index);
  const newNode = { ...curr };
  const matchingNodes = myList.filter((node) => node.ID === curr.ID);
  if (matchingNodes.length > 1 && newNode.color === 'red') {
    newNode.ID += '_OLD';
  }
  acc.push(newNode);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

If you dont want to eliminate those who has only one color, you have to check the length of the matching node list before pushing it to accumulator.

**Working Example**

```js
var myList = [
  { 'ID': 'ES', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'red' },
  { 'ID': 'ES', 'volume': 2, 'color': 'red' },
  { 'ID': 'ES', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'green' },
  { 'ID': 'HH', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'red' },
  { 'ID': 'HR', 'volume': 4, 'color': 'green' },
  { 'ID': 'HR', 'volume': 4, 'color': 'red' },
  { 'ID': 'ES', 'volume': 1, 'color': 'red' }
];
const result = myList.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  console.log(curr, index);
  const newNode = { ...curr };
  const matchingNodes = myList.filter((node) => node.ID === curr.ID);
  if (matchingNodes.length > 1 && newNode.color === 'red') {
    newNode.ID += '_OLD';
  }
  if (matchingNodes.length > 1) {
    acc.push(newNode);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```